# View not found for views with number at the end

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to do a `reverse` like this:

```
print reverse("shows-view")
```

This is in my `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^shows/(\d+)$', views.show_details, name="shows-view"),
```

Whenever I try to do that, it just returns:

```
Reverse for 'shows-view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['shows/(\\d+)$']
```

But if I try to access the page directly (`http://localhost/shows/3333`) then it works fine

But if I do a reverse for other views like this:

```
print reverse("shows-default-view")
```

with the following declaration in the same `urls.py` file:

```
url(r'^shows/', views.popular, name="shows-default-view"),
```

then it works fine. Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL in question accepts an argument `(\d+)` which you are not passing your `reverse` function. Just think: this is a details view, but *which* show do you want to display?

To fix, call `reverse` with the `args` parameter:

```
reverse("shows-default-view", args=[1]) # to show show with id of 1
```

In general for URL's like that, the recommendation is to have a named captured group:

```
url(r'^shows/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.show_details, name="shows-view")
```

And then the call to `reverse` will be:

```
reverse("shows-default-view", kwargs={'pk': 1})
```

To use `reverse` in a template, just put the two arguments together:

```
{% url 'shows-view' 1 %}
```

Comment: Ohhhh that makes sense. How would I pass this argument inside a template? I was doing that because `{% url 'shows-default-view' %}` so that I can dynamically generate the URLs

Comment: @JohnQ added at the end. The more common case is for the id not to be hard-coded, e.g. `show.id` instead of `1`